# How to prove limit of x/(x^2+1) is 2/5 as x approaches 2 using epsilon delta definition

Tags: calculus

Attached is my thought on a scratch paper, but it's messy..not sure if it is right.
click the link directly to see the picture.

[image]

Comment: Isn't there an "enter image description here" button that, if clicked, will direct you to the image?

Comment: Never mind - it was just showing up as zoomed so large, I was only seeing the upper-left corner.

Comment: So can you see the whole picture now? I guess it is because of the image resolution stuff. I can use Photoshop to adjust to normal size if necessary.

Comment: Please use LaTeX to write formulas. Images with hand written formulas are sometimes hard to interpret. `$$\left|\frac{(2x-1)(x-2)}{5x^2+1}\right|$$` for instance gives $$\left|\frac{(2x-1)(x-2)}{5x^2+1}\right|$$

Answer (score 1):

The strategy is right, however you made some transcription errors from one line to the next, esp. changing $5(x^2+1)$ to $5x^2+1$. Calculations you publish should be readable and not contain trivial errors.

So yes, at some point you get to
$$
\left|\frac{2x-1}{5(x^2+1)}\right|·|x-2|\le \frac{2|x-2|+3}{5}·|x-2|
$$
At this point one usually introduces an artificial restriction like $δ\le 1$ to control the first factor as 
$$
2|x-2|+3<2δ+3\le 5
$$
In consequence, the upper bound is $|x-2|$ which allows to chose 
$$
δ=\min(1,ε)
$$

Comment: Sorry. I just knew this forum yesterday. So I'm not quite familiar with how to use LaTex stuff. I'll try to learn that. Anyway, thank you so much!!